# i tag did not pass value to email

Tags: php, html

I have a form that have "i" tag and "input" tag.

The form obtain the information from user and send it to my email via PHP.

I am able to receive the email but the information from "i" tag is missing. I only receive the "input" tag in my email. Here are my code.

```js
typeQue = $("select#need-type").children("option:selected").val();
    if (typeQue === "type-ch" ) {
        var typeFee = 0;
        typeCharges = typeFee;
    }else if (typeQue === "type-1" ) {
        var typeFee = 10;
        typeCharges = typeFee;
    }else if (typeQue === "type-2" ) {
        var typeFee = 20;
        typeCharges = typeFee;
    }
    
    $("#type-result").html('RM' + typeCharges);
```

```html
<form action="forms/custom-quote.php" method="POST" class="needs-validation row" novalidate>

<select name="need-type" type="text" id="need-type">
<option value="type-ch">- Choose type -</option>
<option value="type-1">Coffee</option>
<option value="type-2">Donut</option>
</select>

<input type="text" placeholder="Alif Ibrahim" id="fname" name="custom-name" required>
<label for="fname">Your Name<span style="color:rgb(255, 0, 0)"> *</span></label>

// Here show result from type
<i id = "type-result" type ="text" name = "typeAnswer"></i>

<button class="btn btn-primary w-100" type="submit">Submit Price</button>

</form>
```

I include my php code in image format as when i try to insert it here, it show my post will not be publish.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tags are not form data

Create a hidden input and set that to the same value, and you’ll receive it

```
<i id="type-result"></i>
<input id="type-result-hidden" type="hidden" name="typeAnswer">
```

Then in code

```
$("#type-result").html('RM' + typeCharges);
$("#type-result-hidden").val('RM' + typeCharges);
```

Comment: Thank you for your info about the form data. I've amended my code with your solution but still didn't solve the issue. So I change the "i" tag to some other tag within the form element and now it works like a charm. TQ :)